# Idea to show convergence or divergence of below series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_1>0$ and we have this definition $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{(\sqrt[3]{a_n}+1)^3} ,n=1,2,3,...$$ now the question is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$ converges or not  ?

I get stuck on this problem . can you guide me ? thanks in advance.

Comment: The question about context, own thoughts,... is only relevant for new users with rep below 10k, did I get that right?

Comment: @ProfessorVector :Really It was asked from my colleague . He also stuck on this problem ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some elementary algebra gives $a^{-1/3}_{n+1}=1+a^{-1/3}_{n}$, 
so we have $a^{-1/3}_{n}=a^{-1/3}_1+n-1$, and that means $$a_n=\frac{a_1}{\left(1+a^{1/3}_1(n-1)\right)^3}.$$ But $a_n=O(n^{-3})$ means that the series converges.